# Logs from signal handler hidden when redirecting stdout to file via tee

Tags: python, linux

I have a python program like this:

```
import signal, time

def cleanup(*_):
    print("cleanup")
    # do stuff ...
    exit(1)

# trap ctrl+c and hide the traceback message
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, cleanup)

time.sleep(20)
```

I run the program through a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG1="$1"

trap cleanup INT TERM EXIT

cleanup() {
    echo "\ncleaning up..."
    killall -9 python >/dev/null 2>&1
    killall -9 python3 >/dev/null 2>&1
    # some more killing here ...
}

mystart() {
    echo "starting..."
    export PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)
    python3 -u myfolder/myfile.py $ARG1 2>&1 | tee "myfolder/log.txt"
}

mystart &&
cleanup
```

My problem is that the message *cleanup* isn't appearing on the terminal nor on the log file.

However, if I call the program without redirecting the output it works fine.

Comment: As an aside, in `mystart && cleanup`, whether `cleanup` is run depends on the exit status from `tee`, not the exit status of `python3`; a shell pipeline has the exit status of the last component in it unless `lastpipe` is used (and a function has the return value of the last command in it). That's another behavior that switching to a process substitution will avoid.

Comment: As another aside, `PYTHONPATH=$PWD` is much more efficient than `PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)`, and `killall -9 python` is *really* a bad idea -- that refers not just to your *one* Python program, but to *every* Python program run by the same user (or if this is run as root, every other Python program on the system).

Comment: ...do you really need to worry about your Python program spawning children that don't die on their own (and also don't clean up gracefully when given a SIGTERM and thus require escalation to SIGKILL)? If so, there are techniques to deal with it more gracefully than `killall` -- f/e, opening a lockfile, connecting handle on that lockfile to your Python program, and then using `fuser -k` to kill all processes that have that file open on cleanup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want this to happen, put `tee` in the background so it isn't part of the process group getting a `SIGINT`. For example, with bash 4.1 or newer, you can start a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) with an automatically-allocated file descriptor providing a handle:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^ NOT /bin/sh; >(...) is a bashism, likewise automatic FD allocation.

exec {log_fd}> >(exec tee log.txt)  # run this first as a separate command
python3 -u myfile >&"$log_fd" 2>&1  # then here, ctrl+c will only impact Python...
exec {log_fd}>&-                    # here we close the file & thus the copy of tee.
```

Of course, if you put those three commands *in a script*, that entire script becomes your foreground process, so different techniques are called for. Thus:

```
python3 -u myfile > >(trap '' INT; exec tee log.txt) 2>&1
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned it in the post but I didnt think it would matter: yes, I run my program through a script `myscript.sh`

Comment: Adjusted with a solution that works in that case. (BTW, it's not good form to put `.sh` on shell scripts, any more than you put `.py` on Python executables -- `.py` should be used only on Python *libraries*, and `.sh` on baseline-POSIX shell *libraries* likewise (whereas bash-only shell libraries should use .bash, ksh-only shell libraries .ksh, etc); see https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Comment: ...you'll note how `setup.py install` install creates wrappers for your entry points that don't have any extension on UNIX; that's appropriate, and in accordance with platform convention.

Comment: I've edited my original post to show my calling script. Because I am already trapping signals in it, I think your answer would interfere with it. Sorry I didnt post the script earlier, didnt think it would be needed

Comment: This answer changes the trap only in the process substitution's context, not for the whole script, so it's still safe with your predefined traps. `>(...)` runs `...` in a separate, forked-off interpreter; process-local changes don't propagate back.

Comment: I get the following error when running your solution: `Syntax error: redirection unexpected`

Comment: Make sure your bash is 4.1 or later. If it is, I'd need to see a [mcve] for the error (ideally in an online interpreter like https://ideone.com/).

Comment: I am: `bash is already the newest version (4.4.18-2ubuntu1).`

Comment: You might also check the way you've integrated the answer against http://shellcheck.net/ (you'll note that the versions given above both parse with no errors there when copied-and-pasted without changes).

Comment: Hm... that website doesnt give the error I get when running it on the terminal... The way I'm running it is `sh myscript.sh`

Comment: `sh` is not bash. You must not use `sh` to run bash scripts. (Remember where I said above that using a `.sh` extension for bash scripts is misleading? This is part of why).

Comment: how do I run it then? o_O

Comment: If you set executable permissions for the file, `./myscript.sh` (which honors the `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line at the top to select an interpreter); if you didn't, `bash myscript.sh`. And, again, I advise renaming to remove the extension.

Comment: Using `bash myscript.sh` solved it, thanks! But now echo doesn't escape sequences haha. `echo "\ncleaning up..."` prints exactly that, `\ncleaning up...`. Any way to fix this?

Comment: As the `echo` specification advises, when in doubt, use `printf` instead. `printf '%s\n' '' 'cleaning up...'`, f/e: the `'%s\n'` format string says that each following argument is to be printed verbatim with a single newline after it; the first argument is an empty string (so it prints just a newline), and the second one is `cleaning up...`. Or `printf '%b\n' '\ncleaning...'`, or just `printf '\ncleaning...\n'` if you don't need flexibility to include variable expansions safely; lots of options.

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, particularly the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: BTW, another option is to use the Python `logging` module to configure logs to go to both stdout or stderr and `log.txt`, and not need a shell script involved at all. (Similarly, if you have threads that aren't getting cleaned up, setting the daemon flag on them in Python will cause them to be killed when the main interpreter dies without needing an external forcing function).

Answer (score 3):

Pressing `^C` sends `SIGINT` to the entire [foreground process *group*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_184) (the current pipeline or shell “job”), killing `tee` before it can write the output from your handler anywhere.  You can use `trap` in the shell to immunize a command against `SIGINT`, although that comes with obvious risks.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `-i` or `--ignore-interrupts` option of `tee`.
Documentation says:

```
-i, --ignore-interrupts
    ignore interrupt signals
```

https://helpmanual.io/man1/tee/